# Translating two javascript terms into AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I'm working with a JS script that someone developed for me but I need to convert it to AS3. I'm good with AS3 but a bit baffled re: how to translate these two lines into AS3.

1. var teams = Array.apply(null, {length: numOfTeams}).map(Number.call, Number)
2. the following snippet with backwards single quotes

```js
pairs[`${i},${x}`] = true;
```

Although the script runs fine in a JS interpreter, I'm not sure what "`" denotes and I'm thinking that "apply" and "map" may have been around in AS2 when it was prototype-based but I never used AS2. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in modern JS the back tick represents string interpolation. I don't think there is an equivalent in AS3. Inside back ticks you can use `${}` to wrap a variable in a string.

Taking the example and imagining some input

```
var i = 1;
var x = 2;
`${i},${x}`
// outputs "1,2" as a string

var i = "Foo";
var x = "Bar";
`${i},${x}`
// outputs "Foo,Bar" as a string
```

It just concatenates two variables with a comma in between.
It could be written the same way.

```
var i = 1;
var x = 2;
i + "," + x
// outputs "1,2" as a string
```

It reads like you have an Object `pairs` with `i comma x` as a key and boolean as a value.

```
{
  "1,2": true,
  "0,0": false,
  "4,5": true,
  "9,3": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

``` `` ``` denotes a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which means that `${i},${x}` will be replaced with whatever the variable `i` contains, a comma, and then whatever the variable `x` contains.  The following two are equivalent:

```js
pairs = {};
i = 'hello'
x = 'world'
pairs[`${i},${x}`] = true;

console.log(pairs)

pairs = {}
pairs[i + ',' + x] = true
console.log(pairs)
```

[.apply](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html) looks like it existed in AS3, as does [`.map`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#map())

Comment: Both of these comments are very helpful on the variable placeholders. Just trying to figure how apply and map could be represented in AS3. Is this creating an array and assigning values to fill the array and if so, is Number a class that's being called in javascript.

Comment: Guess I'll give credit for the first answer and create a new question confined to the Array question. Thanks

Comment: ...both of those exist in AS3, see the links at the bottom of my answer.  Or do you mean the `.Number` stuff - it's just creating an array where each item is the index.  You could just as easily do `teams = []; for (i = 0; i < numTeams; i++) { teams.push(i); }`

Comment: Thanks much. Appreciate the clarification.